# Cloudera's CDH4 WordCount hadoop tutorial - issues

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I am following this tutorial:
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/HadoopTutorial/CDH4/Hadoop-Tutorial/ht_topic_5_2.html

It says the following:

> javac -cp classpath -d wordcount_classes WordCount.java
>
> where classpath is:
>
> ```
> CDH4 - /usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/*
> CDH3 - /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u4-core.jar
> ```

I have downloaded the "cloudera-quickstart-demo-vm-4.2.0-vmware" .
Running as user cloudera.

```
    [cloudera@localhost wordcount]$ javac -cp /usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/* -d wordcount_classes WordCount.java
incorrect classpath: /usr/lib/hadoop/*
incorrect classpath: /usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/*
----------
1. ERROR in WordCount.java (at line 8)
        import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

When checking the cp folder: .

```
[cloudera@localhost wordcount]$ ls -l /usr/lib/hadoop
total 3500
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    4096 Apr 22 14:37 bin
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    4096 Apr 22 14:33 client
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    4096 Apr 22 14:33 client-0.20
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    4096 Apr 22 14:36 cloudera
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    4096 Apr 22 14:30 etc
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   16536 Feb 15 14:24 hadoop-annotations-2.0.0-cdh4.2.0.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      37 Apr 22 14:30 hadoop-annotations.jar -> hadoop-annotations-2.0.0-cdh4.2.0.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   46855 Feb 15 14:24 hadoop-auth-2.0.0-cdh4.2.0.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      30 Apr 22 14:30 hadoop-auth.jar -> hadoop-auth-2.0.0-cdh4.2.0.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2266171 Feb 15 14:24 hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.2.0.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1212163 Feb 15 14:24 hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.2.0-tests.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      32 Apr 22 14:30 hadoop-common.jar -> hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.2.0.jar
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root    4096 Apr 22 14:36 lib
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    4096 Apr 22 14:33 libexec
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    4096 Apr 22 14:31 sbin
```

What am I doing wrong?
This is directly from the Cloudera Quickstart VM with CDH4 installed.
Following the "Hadoop Tutorial" .
It even says

```
**Prerequisites**

Ensure that CDH is installed, configured, and running. The easiest way to get going quickly is to use a CDH4 QuickStart VM
```

Which is exactly from where I am running this tutorial from - the CDH4 QuickStart VM.

What am I doing wrong?

*update
Version information;

```
[cloudera@localhost cloudera]$ cat cdh_version.properties

# Autogenerated build properties
version=2.0.0-cdh4.2.0
git.hash=8bce4bd28a464e0a92950c50ba01a9deb1d85686
cloudera.hash=8bce4bd28a464e0a92950c50ba01a9deb1d85686
cloudera.base-branch=cdh4-base-2.0.0
cloudera.build-branch=cdh4-2.0.0_4.2.0
cloudera.pkg.version=2.0.0+922
cloudera.pkg.release=1.cdh4.2.0.p0.12
cloudera.cdh.release=cdh4.2.0
cloudera.build.time=2013.02.15-18:39:29GMT

cloudera.pkg.name=hadoop
```

CLASSPATH ENV:

```
[cloudera@localhost bin]$ echo $CLASSPATH
:/usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/*
```

**EDIT!!
So I think I figured it out.
This is a new issue possibly with the Cloudera CD4 VM quickstart VM:
from: [This Post](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cdh-user/lgIFnBGC0h0) dated yesterday
Another person was having the exact same problem.**
It seems the javac program does not accept wildcards properly on exported paths.
I had to do the following:

```
export CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/\*:/usr/lib/hadoop/\*
```

Then
javac -d   [Without a -cp override]

```
javac -d wordcount_classes/ WordCount.java
```

Only warnings will appear.

I wonder if Cloudera has to fix their quickstart VM.

Comment: make sure the cdh4 libraries are where you think they should be, this error is just saying it can't find the hadoop libs

Comment: How do I know where the libraries are? i did a 'hadoop classpath' command, even tried everything within there.  nothing.

Comment: try doing a `ls /usr/lib/hadoop/` what is inside there?

Comment: I have updated my original post showing all files in /usr/lib/hadoop.

Comment: what does the command $: echo $CLASSPATH produce

Comment: added to the end of my original post

Comment: Nice, I am using this same VM and have run that tutorial w/o errors. the only thing I did as a matter of practice was to set the classpath at runtime only because I was not sure if the application was setting it. If it was getting appended twice it would not matter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a classpath variable set that includes those directories in /usr/lib/hadoop if you want javac to find them. You can set this env var as follows

```
$: export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/*
```

javac will now find those libs. If you have any additional complaining regarding classpath variables you can just append them to the above line using a colon (:) as a delimiter

You could include this in a bash script, but it is best practice to set the correct env variables at runtime, then you get exactly what you want. In this case it could be word count or the CDH4 env is setting it, but it is best to just set it yourself.

Comment: Thanks.  Getting the same error .. Problem is I'm not sure where else the libraries would be.  I am following the tutorial 100%.

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time searching for a response to the same issue (also using VM with CDH4) so I shall leave my solution here in hopes that it might help others.

Unfortunately, neither of the solutions above worked in my case.

However, I was able to successfully compile the example by closing my terminal and opening a new one. My issue was having previously switched to the 'cloudera' user with 'sudo su cloudera' as mentioned in the tutorial.

Reference:

http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Apache-Hadoop-Concepts-and/Classpath-Problem-on-WordCount-Tutorial-QuickStart-VM-4-4-0-1/td-p/3613